# Query is not running correctly

Tags: oracle

> ERROR CODE ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

```
  SELECT invoice_no,
         item_no
         SUM (
              invoice_ship_handle
            + invoice_tax
            + invoice_deposit
            + item_unit_price * item_qty_shipped)
            AS "Total Item Cost"
    FROM invoices_s, items_sold_s
GROUP BY item_no, invoice_no
ORDER BY SUM (
              invoice_ship_handle
            + invoice_tax
            + invoice_deposit
            + item_unit_price * item_qty_shipped) DESC;
```

Comment: There is a comma missing in the second line after item_no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a comma between the `item_no` and the `sum` expression:

```
  SELECT invoice_no,
         item_no,
         -- Here^
         SUM (
              invoice_ship_handle
            + invoice_tax
            + invoice_deposit
            + item_unit_price * item_qty_shipped)
            AS "Total Item Cost"
    FROM invoices_s, items_sold_s
GROUP BY item_no, invoice_no
ORDER BY SUM (
              invoice_ship_handle
            + invoice_tax
            + invoice_deposit
            + item_unit_price * item_qty_shipped) DESC;
```